# Datatables search, filter, and export with Firebase

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, datatables, angularfire

I have a CRUD app powered by angular. Recently I added datatables to it in order  to search, filter, sort,export and hide columns using the power of datatables. Unfortunately it returns the Firebase references in the various columns `{{contact.name}}` `{{contact.email}}` (There are 4 more columns) when I use any datatables feature such as search it returns the Firebase reference instead of a field. Is there a way to fix this? I really need those datatable features at the same time use Firebase.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contacts').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<table id="contacts" class="table table-striped table-hover" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th> Actions </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.area}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.work}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
      <td><a href="#/edit/{{contact.$id}}" class="btn btn-raised btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-raised btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="removeContact(contact.$id)">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Will sourcing the data via ajax sort this out. This is the json format i get from the ajax GET request

```html
{"-KIZ6VnucsKbKjlaE8aq":{"area":"Parklands","email":"tttt","name":"Mohammed Sohail","phone":"+254700000000","work":"ttt"},"-KId6OC2gOwiacUid9yK":{"area":"dfgdfg","email":"dfgdf","name":"dfg","phone":"dfgdfg","work":"fdfffffff"},"-KId6Rqo0B6w0jACHhWM":{"area":"dfgdfgdfgdf","email":"dfgdfgdfgdfg","name":"dfgfdgdf","phone":"gdfgdfgdfg","work":"gdfgdfgdfgdfg"},"-KIqmYZubPYhAqDqEyWo":{"area":"dfgfdg","email":"fgfdgfdgdf","name":"fgfg","phone":"fdgdg","work":"fgdfgdf"},"-KIqn5QABMXrTGoVgQv1":{"area":"bla","email":"weadasda","name":"bla","phone":"bla","work":"bla"}}
```

And this is how the data looks like on the console.

Any help to use data tables will be appriciated.

[FireBase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJoUi.png)

Comment: Please post relevant code within the question itself. Links rot and we shouldn't have to go poke through a repo to find your code. Questions should be self contained so we don't have to go off site to review the issues. Also the problem statement is not clear at all. No idea what *"returns the array"* means without proper context and expected results See: [ask]

Comment: Ok will edit it. I am using it from a phone.

Comment: How you input/edit question is irrelevant. What matters is that it conforms to site guidelines and problem is clear and question contains all relevant details including the problem code

Comment: I have done what I can, help if you can.

Comment: done what? problem is not clear and there is no code shown. See [mcve]. If you want help you need to put the proper effort into creating an answerable question

Comment: I have posted the code in the gist....right above the tags...come on man. You will understand the problem when you see the gist.

Comment: What part of *"code belongs in question"* is hard for you to understand. Questions should be self contained. That link can rot in future making whole question useless for others

Comment: You probably want to use angular dataTables module

Comment: Alright fixed everything. P.S undo downvote if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this question is really about turning a (firebase) JSON object of objects with unknown object entry names such as KId6Rqo0B6w0jACHhWM into a more plain structure that can be used along with dataTables and `ng-repeat`?

You can format `contacts` into an array of plain objects this way :

```js
$http.get('firebase.json').then(function(json) { //faked response from firebase
  $scope.contacts = []
  for (var item in json.data) {
    $scope.contacts.push(json.data[item]) 
  }
})
```

Now the `ng-repeat` will work and the markup (or `contacts` data) is understandable for dataTables. To turn this into [**angular-datatables**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) (angular directives for jQuery dataTables) the only thing you need to do is to include the `datatables` dependency and include the `datatable` directive in the markup :

```html
<table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-hover" >
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/tn9cuKa46vs4x8cHebjB?p=preview**

Comment: works perfect, supposing i want to add buttons? I can get the bootstrap styling on but not the buttons, documentation is a bit off. could you show me the added buttons on plnkr real quick. I would really appreciate.

Comment: i just want to simplify everything yet use select and export functions, even if it means bypassing angular. any tips?

Comment: @MohammedSohail - basically do the same as in the docs -> https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons but you MUST include `jszip` and `pdfmake`, and `jszip` MUST be `2.6.0` or below, i.e `bower install jszip#2.6.0 --save`.